# Help regardign weird shadows

Tags: eevee-render-engine

So I have a question that has happened to me in other projects and I don't understand. So sometimes I have like a "square" shadow being generated on the renders. Even if I turn off the shadows option from the lights, I have no idea how to fix this or why it's happening, any help? FYI: I'm using EEVEE as I don't have a laptop capable of running Cycles

Sorry if there is a dumb solution, I just started blender :(

[image]

[image]